# HTTP Authorization and WWW-Authenticate headers

Tags: rest, security, http, authentication, http-headers

I'm developing a REST API and now, I would like to introduce an authentication/authorization system, after a long research I decided to implement an HTTP authentication with [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code), something very similar to the [Amazon implementation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html).
But I don't understand how the scheme works... For example Amazon makes use of a custom "AWS" scheme... is the scheme name arbitrary? (Can I define any name for it like "foo", "bar", "my_api_scheme" and so on?)

My guess is that it's possible to choose a scheme name of any type, provided that the same name is used in the `WWW-Authenticate` header.
So if I want to create a "`my_api`" scheme I would return a 401 http response with:

```
WWW-Authenticate: my_api realm="user.mysite.com"
```

and in the request:

```
Authorization: my_api hash_signature
```

Am I right or is not so simple?

Comment: You may want to read <http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7235.html>.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what you propose is correct. You should probably base64 encode the `hash_signature`. You can find how the AWS authentication scheme works [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html).

Whether it's a good idea to write your own authentication logic is another question. I'd advise you to look into something like [Hawk](https://github.com/hueniverse/hawk), which does what you want and is maintained by people who are subject matter experts.